# Surface-of- section for a system of coupled oscillators

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear

For the following system of non linear coupled ODEs:

\begin{align}
& \ddot{x}=-x^{1/3}+k_2(y-x)^{1/3} \\
& \ddot{y}=-k_2(y-x)^{1/3}
\end{align}

and the corresponding potential function:

\begin{equation}
V(x,y)=\frac{3}{4}\left( x^{4/3}+k_2(y-x)^{4/3} \right) 
\end{equation}

I would like to produce some surfaces of section for various values of $k_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ which controls the coupling term.

For the sections, I have the following piece of code:

```
SurfaceOfSection[{x0_, {y0_, dy0_}, e_}, tmax_] := 
  Module[
      {dx0 = 
         Sqrt[2 e -dy0^2 - (2/(μ + 1)) (Abs[x0]^(μ + 1) + 2*Abs[y0 - x0]^(μ + 1))], 
       x, y, t},
    If[# == {}, {}, First[#]] & @ 
      Last[
        Reap[
          NDSolve[
            {x''[t] == -CubeRoot[x[t]] + 2 CubeRoot[(y[t] - x[t])],
             y''[t] == -2 CubeRoot[y[t] - x[t]],
             y[0] == y0, y'[0] == dy0, x[0] == x0, x'[0] == dx0},
            {x, y}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
            Method -> 
              {EventLocator, "Event" -> x[t], 
               "EventAction" :> Sow[{y[t], y'[t]}]}] 
            Assumptions :> {Element[x, Reals], Element[y, Reals]}]]
```

where I chose in this case `μ=1/3` and $k_2=2$, on the plane $y, \dot{y}$. As it can be seen, I have solved the energy equation with respect to $\dot{x}$:

\begin{equation}
\dot{x}=\sqrt{2E-\dot{y}^2-\frac{3}{2}\left( |x|^{4/3}+k_2|(y-x)|^{4/3} \right)}
\end{equation}

where I **had** to use `Abs[x]` and `Abs[y - x]` as well the `CubeRoot[x[t]]^(μ)`, since *Mathematica* by default returns the principal value of a number raised to a rational exponent:

```
N[(-1)^(1/3)] = 0.5 + 0.866025 I
```

and not the **real** root which is needed in this case for the sections. *(in fact I got an error message when I was trying to iterate without the `Abs[]`)*.

While I was able to (slowly) get some plots in the following way

```
x = Array[0 &, 151];
Do[
  x[[i]] = 
   Join @@ 
     Table[SurfaceOfSection[{0.001, {0, 0.01*(i - 1)}, 1.2}, 3000], {1}], 
  {i,151}]
l = Catenate[Table[x[[i]], {i, 151}]];
With[{x = .0001},
  Internal`DeactivateMessages[
    ListPlot[l,
      PlotStyle -> {PointSize[.001], Red},
      AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio, 
      AxesLabel -> TraditionalForm /@ {y[t], Overscript[y, .][t]},
      ImageSize -> 500, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]]
```

[image: ]]

I was wondering the following:

- How is it possible to acquire the correct result when evaluating `x_0^(μ+1)` and `(y_0-x_0)^(μ+1)` without using the absolute value of it? By doing so I am only getting back the positive corresponding point on the Sections which creates a false behavior on the dynamics of the ODEs. There must be a way to tell *Mathematica* to return the real root of these quantities.
- Is it possible to acquire the resulting plots faster? In order to get a satisfying result I had to use `tmax=3000` which took like half an hour of calculations on my laptop.

Comment: Could add a `Re` around the trouble some part?

Comment: @user21 Would that return only the real part of the principal value? If yes, then it is wrong, since `Re[N[(-1)^(1/3)]]=0.5` for Mathematica,, but the real root is `(-1)^(1/3)=-1`.

Comment: Try `Surd`, which gives the real root of any real quantity.

Comment: Use `Surd[-1, 3]`.

Comment: Is `Surd[x_0,μ+1]` the correct way to write the $x_0^{\mu+1}$?

Comment: The correct way appears to be `Surd[x0^(Numerator@(mu + 1)), Denominator@(mu + 1)]`, because the second argument must be an integer.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Indeed, it seems to be correct. Thank you. The algorithm is not possible to be optimized right?

Comment: Almost any code can be optimized to a degree.  I would have to give some thought before providing you a credible answer.

Comment: You write `NDSolve[ ...] Assumptions :> {Element[x, Reals], Element[y, Reals]}`. I think this must be a typo, because the full form of this expression is `HoldForm[RuleDelayed[Times[NDSolve[...], Assumptions], List[Element[x, Reals], Element[y, Reals]]]]`, which is nonsense.

Comment: @m_goldberg Thank you for your answer. What should I change in these assumptions to correct the code?

Comment: You also write `Join @@ Table[SurfaceOfSection[{0.001, {0, 0.01*(i - 1)}, 1.2}, 3000], {1}]` which just gives `Table[SurfaceOfSection[{0.001, {0, 0.01*(i - 1)}, 1.2}, 3000]`. What were you really trying to compute?

Comment: m_goldberg I thought it was obvious that I am not really familiar with this kind of computations, hence the question about the code optimization. I would appreciate any corrections which could improve the code. Thank you :)

Comment: `NDSolve` doesn't pay attention to assumptions, so just remove ` Assumptions :> {Element[x, Reals], Element[y, Reals]` from your code.

Comment: By the way, "WhenEvent" is preferred over "EventLocator" in newer versions of Mathematica.

Comment: there are a couple of syntax errors in your post, unbalanced parenthesis and there is a missing comma before `Assumptions`

Comment: @george2079 Thank you for your answer. Would you mind going over the syntax errors, so that I can correct them, also the parenthesis?

Comment: @bbgodfrey I will have to check the way it is defined,  and then change it, thank you :)

Comment: you were missing a square bracket at the very end of each block. No doubt just a copy paste error.  The `Assumptions` option should be removed anyway. Always a good idea to copy your posted code back and make sure it works.   BTW I made it run just a wee bit faster using `-y''` instead of the `CubeRoot` in the first equation.  Sorry there isn't much room for improvement I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SurfaceOfSection` can be simplified,

```
SurfaceOfSection[{x0_, {y0_, dy0_}, e_}, tmax_] := 
    Reap[NDSolve[{x''[t] == -CubeRoot[x[t]] + 2 CubeRoot[(y[t] - x[t])], 
    y''[t] == -2 CubeRoot[y[t] - x[t]], y[0] == y0, y'[0] == dy0, x[0] == x0, 
    x'[0] == Sqrt[2 e - dy0^2 - (2/(4/3)) (Surd[x0^4, 3] + 2*Surd[(y0 - x0)^4, 3])], 
    WhenEvent[x[t] == 0, Sow[{y[t], y'[t]}]]}, {}, {t, 0, tmax}]][[2, 1]]
```

but the simplifications reduce runtime by only about 5%, mostly from replacing `{x, y}` by `{ }`.  As recommended in the comments, using `Surd` effectively addresses the first issue in the question.  Then, reduction by a factor of three or more is achieved with `ParallelTable` (on a four-processor PC)

```
l = Join @@ ParallelTable[
    SurfaceOfSection[{0.001, {0, 0.01*(i - 1)}, 1.2}, 3000], {i, 151}];
```

after which

```
ListPlot[l, PlotStyle -> {PointSize[.001], Red}, AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio, 
    ImageSize -> 500, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

reproduces the plot in the question.  For completeness `Length@l` is `113793`.

**Minor Generalization**

In response to comments below, the earlier computation can be generalized as follows.

```
SurfaceOfSection[μ_, κ_, {x0_, {y0_, dy0_}, e_}, tmax_] := 
    Reap[NDSolve[{x''[t] == -Surd[x[t]^(Numerator@μ), Denominator@μ] + 
      κ*Surd[(y[t] - x[t])^(Numerator@μ), Denominator@μ], 
    y''[t] == -κ*Surd[(y[t] - x[t])^(Numerator@μ), Denominator@μ], 
    y[0] == y0, y'[0] == dy0, x[0] == x0, 
    x'[0] == Sqrt[2 e - dy0^2 - (2/(μ + 1)) (Surd[x0^(Numerator@(μ + 1)), 
      Denominator@(μ + 1)] + κ*Surd[(y0 - x0)^(Numerator@(μ + 1)), Denominator@(μ + 1)])], 
    WhenEvent[x[t] == 0, Sow[{y[t], y'[t]}]]}, {}, {t, 0, tmax}]][[2, 1]]
```

Then, the results above are reproduced by

```
l = Join @@ ParallelTable[
    SurfaceOfSection[1/3, 2, {0.001, {0, 0.01*(i - 1)}, 1.2}, 3000], {i, 151}];
```

Comment: Seems like a new laptop would be of good use to me. :) Thank you @bbgodfrey!

Comment: Btw I tried to run and got the following error message `Transpose::nmtx :  The first two levels of {} cannot be transposed.`. Is it something wrong that am I doing?

Comment: @Mitscaype  What were you running?  What version of Mathematica do you have?  With respect to a new PC, if you buy one with four processors, I recommend you also obtain 16GB of memory.  A solid state disk (in addition to a standard disk) is convenient but not necessary.  If you do purchase a PC with SSD, be sure it is at least 200GB.

Comment: I ran your enhanced version of `SurfaceofSection` and then `l = Join @@ ParallelTable[
    SurfaceOfSection[{0.001, {0, 0.01*(i - 1)}, 1.2}, 3000], {i, 151}];` which gave me back the error. I have Mathematica 11.0 on a Dell Windows 7, Intel i3-2350M and 4GB of memory. He is old but still going the distance :) Thanks for the tips btw, I was thinking of adding SSD after the purchase usually it is a bit cheaper.

Comment: @Mitscaype  I copied the code in my answer to a fresh notebook and ran it without difficulty using Version 11.1.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: `SurfaceOfSection[{x0_, {y0_, dy0_}, e_}, tmax_] :=Reap[NDSolve[{x''[t] == -Surd[x[t]^(Numerator@(\[Mu]-1)),Denominator@(\[Mu] - 1)]*x[t]+\[Kappa]*Surd[(y[t]-x[t])^(Numerator@(\[Mu] - 1)),Denominator@(\[Mu] - 1)]*(y[t] - x[t]),y''[t]==-\[Kappa]*Surd[(y[t] - x[t])^(Numerator@(\[Mu] - 1)),Denominator@(\[Mu] - 1)]*(y[t] - x[t]), y[0] == y0,y'[0] == dy0, x[0] == x0,x'[0] ==Sqrt[2 e-dy0^2 - (2/(\[Mu] + 1)) (Surd[x0^(Numerator@(\[Mu]+1)),Denominator@(\[Mu] + 1)] + \[Kappa]*Surd[(y0-x0)^(Numerator@(\[Mu] + 1)),Denominator@(\[Mu]+ 1)])],WhenEvent[x[t]==0,Sow[{y[t], y'[t]}]]},{}, {t, 0, tmax}]][[2,1]]`

Comment: I messed a little bit with it to make it work for every `μ`. Do you think it is a problem?

Comment: @Mitscaype  What values are you using for `\[Mu]` and `\[Kappa]` when you encounter the error?

Comment: @ I used `\[Mu]=1/3` and `\[Kappa]=2`.

Comment: @Mitscaype How are you inserting these values into `SurfaceOfSection`?  Using `{...} /. {μ = 1/3,κ = 2} does not work. However, With[{μ = 1/3, κ = 2}, ...]` does.  Perhaps better would be to add `μ` and `κ` as additional arguments of `SurfaceOfSection`.  By the way, your expressions for `x''[t]` and `y''[t]` can be simplified.

Comment: I was just defining `μ=1/3; κ=2` outside of the `SurfaceofSection` each time. Adding a `With[...]` can work too, true. Simplified in what way you mean?

Comment: @Mitscaype See the addition to my answer for an approach that I have just verified.

Comment: Ah, you meant the part `x[t]^(Numerator@(\[Mu]-1)),Denominator@(\[Mu] - 1)]*x[t]` which is actually `x[t]^(Numerator@(\[Mu])),Denominator@(\[Mu] )]` right? You are correct, I totally missed it.

Comment: I have run your optimized code to a fresh notebook and it works. Thank you for helping me all the way.

Comment: Sorry to return, I would like to add the following note: Would it also be possible somehow to differently color the orbits originating from different ICs at the plot of the section? I have seen some examples at the`Reap` online documentation where they do it. Thanks!

Comment: @Mitscaype  Easy to do.  Omit `Join` from the definition of `l` and `Red` from `PlotStyle`, and the set of points from each IC will have color chosen by `ListPlot`.  However, after enough ICs, `ListPlot` will repeat colors.  To prevent that, you must define your own table of `PlotStyle` values.